# AVAudioplayer jumping on looping in iOS 8 GM with CAFs. Any ideas?

Tags: loops, avaudioplayer, ios8, caf

My app uses AAC encoded CAF files that have been seamlessly looping since iOS 5. Now, with iOS 8 GM there is a gap/break after the loop and it's terrible. There was a thread on Apple's dev forums about this but so far no solution.

Any ideas what to do? I'd hate to have to throw in a 3rd party tool at this point. Let me know if you have any thoughts -- thanks -

Comment: Is there any 3rd party solution?